# what is difference between glassfish configuration, server, instance and cluster?

Tags: glassfish-3

following is a paragraph from glassfish 3.1.2.2 administration guide

> You can rotate log files manually by using the rotate-log subcommand
>   in remote mode. The default target of this subcommand is the DAS.
>   Optionally, you can target a **configuration, server, instance, or
>   cluster**.You can rotate log files manually by using the rotate-log
>   subcommand in remote mode. The default target of this subcommand is
>   the DAS. Optionally, you can target a configuration, server, instance,
>   or cluster.

what is the difference between configuration, server, instance and cluster ? i understand cluster is a collection of instances. but what is difference between server and instance and configuration ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Glassfish admin guide:

> The default target for these two subcommands is the DAS. However, you
> can optionally specify one of the following targets:
>
> **Configuration**: to target all instances or clusters that share a specific configuration name.
> **Server**: to target only a specific server.
> **Instance**: to target only a specific instance.
> **Cluster**: to target only a specific cluster.

> A GlassFish Server instance is a single Virtual Machine for the Java
> platform (Java Virtual Machine or JVM machine) on a single node in
> which GlassFish Server is running. A node defines the host where the
> GlassFish Server instance resides.

and

> It is usually sufficient to create a single server instance on a
> machine, since GlassFish Server and accompanying JVM are both designed
> to scale to multiple processors. However, it can be beneficial to
> create multiple instances on one machine for application isolation and
> rolling upgrades.

This means you can have multiple **instances** of glassfish running on a single **server**, and you can either target a single instance or the whole server.

Comment: so if i understand it is possible to point a single ejb to be deployed for single server instance and other one into another jvm instance, is it correct?