# GlassFish server thread settings vs domain thread settings

Tags: multithreading, jakarta-ee, configuration, glassfish, admin

When I open admin console of any domain I see the below list in *Configurations -> server-config -> Thread pools*:

- admin-thread-pool
- http-thread-pool
- thread-pool-1

So I conclude that thread settings are set for every domain. However, when I read https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1751/abluc/index.html I see no one word about domain settings. Besides, when I do

```
asadmin> help list-threadpools
```

I get

```
Valid values are as follows:
   server
       Lists the thread pools for the default GlassFish Server
       instance server.

   configuration-name
       Lists the thread pools for the named configuration.

   cluster-name
       Lists the thread pools for every instance in the cluster.

   instance-name
       Lists the thread pools for a particular instance.
```

As you see the help says about GlassFish Server instance server. From here https://stackoverflow.com/a/15324447/5057736

> A GlassFish Server instance is a single Virtual Machine for the Java
>   platform (Java Virtual Machine or JVM machine) on a single node in
>   which GlassFish Server is running. A node defines the host where the
>   GlassFish Server instance resides.

Could anyone explain how server thread settings merge(?) with domain thread settings? Correct me if I understand something wrong.

This question is important for me because I must understand how to make most optimal settings when I have many GlassFish domains (>20) on one instance of GlassFish server.

Comment: @BalusC Could you give a hint where I can read this information because I know you are one of the best specialist about java-ee on SO.

Comment: Sorry, I don't do GlassFish ops. I'd personally have asked it on Server Fault, not here.

Comment: @BalusC Thank you for idea.